# Limiting or filtering a graphql query using apollo-express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I am new to graphql. I am building a react site with graphql on the backend. I am trying to figure out how to limit the number of objects (or items) returned by the resolver. Documentation is very scarce and i did not see clear examples for filtering or limiting or sorting things.

my index file looks like this:

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import {ApolloServer, gql} from "apollo-server-express";
import {resolvers} from "./resolver"
import {typeDefs} from "./typeDefs"
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const server = async () => {

    const app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,OPTIONS');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
          return res.sendStatus(200);
        }
        next();
      });


    const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers
    })

    server.applyMiddleware({app})

    await mongoose.connect("mongoaddr...",{useNewUrlParser:true})

    app.get('/', (req,res)=> res.send('hello'))
    app.listen({port:4001}, ()=>{
        console.log('connected')
    })

}

server()
```

My model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
export const Post = mongoose.model("Post",{
    word:String, 

    )
```

my typeDefs:

```
import {gql} from "apollo-server-express";
export const typeDefs = gql`

type Query{

    getPosts(limit:Int):[Post!]!

}
type Post {
    id:ID!
    word: String!

}
```

And my resolver:

```
import { Post } from "./models/Post";


export const resolvers = {
    Query:{

        async getPosts(_,{ limit },context){
            const post = Post.find()
            console.log(limit)
            return(post)

        }}

}
Mutation:{...}
```

I do not understand at all how to limit the getPosts query. With Posts.find() i get all the items in my website but when i console.log it it gives me a huge chunk of metadata.

Could anybody please give an example of how to filter for lets say first 10 objects based on my situation. The data that i am filtering is in mongo db. so basically a standard json like :

```
{
  "data": {
    "getPosts": [
      {
        "word": "test"
      },
      {
        "word": "test1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: use mongo limit - check docs, pass parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to `grapql` at all! You have to slice the array of documents you are getting from your your mongoose model. In your case the `getPosts` function will return an array of `Post` documents. So, you just have to slice & return the array.

```js
async getPosts(_,{ limit },context){
  const post = Post.find()
  return post.slice(0, limit)
}}
```

Or even better, you could use `mongoose` limits:

```
async getPosts(_,{ limit },context){
  const post = Post.find().limit(limit)
  return post
}}
```

That's it .

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already figured that out by chance. I dont understand why people downvoted my question or your answer, because it is correct. How a noob in graphql that  just followed a few youtube tutorials to get it to run suppose to know that .find() is a specific mongoose syntax? Just needed to know that resolvers use mongoose language. Thank you anyway!